# I'm making many related but separate queries on a single large table. Can I combine these somehow and reuse some subqueries?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a large table, say ~1 million rows. At runtime, I need to perform an analysis of this table given some parameters. The analysis performs several queries, some related, some not.

Given the table

```
create table "Participant" (
  "championId" integer NOT NULL,
  "keystone" integer NOT NULL,
  "mythic" integer,
)
```

I need

1. Number of Participants
2. Number of Participants where championId = n
3. Number of Participants grouped by keystone
4. Number of Participants grouped by mythic
5. ... many more queries I will want to make in the future similar to the above ones

I don't have a lot of experience with SQL, but the way I would think of solving this programatically would be to

1. Get all the rows and count them
2. Extract the subset of rows that has championId = n, call it S, and count them
3. Group subset S by keystone, and count each value
4. Group subset S by mythic, and count each value
5. ...

But now that I'm actually implementing the server that performs the query, it seems that I need to make 4 separate queries:

```
select count(*) from "Participant";
select count(*) from "Participant" where "championId" = n;
select keystone, count(*) from "Participant" where "championId" = n group by keystone;
select mythic, count(*) from "Participant" where "championId" = n group by keystone;
...
```

This seems bad to me because

1. 4 separate round trips to the database
2. 4 separate queries that must be made from scratch. The results of some queries should be able to be reused for others. Query 3 < Query 2 < Query 1, and Query 4 < Query 2. That is, the rows of query 2 are a subset of the rows of query 1. So having to go through all the rows again seems bad to me.

How do I improve my workflow?

Comment: Look at *conditional case expressions*

Comment: I would advise considering "Views" to solve tasks related with the structure "Query 3 < Query 2 < Query 1 and Query 4 < Query 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be thinking of this the wrong way. Speaking to your specific concerns...

> 4 separate round trips to the database

Yes, that's true but ideally these would be happening *simultaneously*. Ie. you shouldn't be waiting for query 1 to return before you fire off query 2. Running the queries in parallel effectively makes the round-trip latency a constant.

How you achieve this comes down to the platform/language your app (the thing issuing these queries) is built in. You many need to reach for some async/await or threading tooling.

> 4 separate queries that must be made from scratch. The results of some queries should be able to be reused for others. Query 3 < Query 2 < Query 1, and Query 4 < Query 2. That is, the rows of query 2 are a subset of the rows of query 1. So having to go through all the rows again seems bad to me.

It's tempting to think this when you see multiple queries with similar conditions. The (sometimes counter-intuitive) fact is, database are pretty good at resolving queries against a well indexed table and, generally, the simpler the query, the easier it is for the query planner to build a query that will resolve quickly. Trying to be clever by building more complex queries can sometime backfire.

For example, pulling all the records where `"championId" = 1` out then performing multiple queries against it might seem like a good idea but, in reality this may require the DB to copy a huge amount of data to memory. Plus, this temporary dataset may not be indexed the same way the original table was, meaning the subsequent queries, although they're running against a smaller dataset, may still be slower.

There definitely are times when isolating a small set of expensive data then querying it multiple ways is the right solution but the example you've given isn't one of them. Put another way, you might be overthinking it. Postgres is a powerful and mature platform that's entire job is consuming queries. Simple comparisons that hit indexed columns will generally be surprisingly fast.

(It all depends on your specifics though so if in doubt, benchmark it.)

---

### Ok, But I Still Wanna

Still want to combine multiple queries together even though it's probably not necessary? Ok, let's try it..

A single query is always going to return a single record set. That is, you're always going to get back a "rectangular" set of data, where each row has a value for each column (even if it's `null`). As such, there's 2 was you can add additional data into a query: by adding more rows or by adding more columns.

First lets setup some test data:

```sql
-- Create table
create table "Participant" (
  "championId" integer NOT NULL,
  "keystone" integer NOT NULL,
  "mythic" integer
);

-- Create some random test data
insert into "Participant" ("championId", "keystone", "mythic")
select floor(random() * 10 + 1) as "championId", floor(random() * 10 + 1) as "keystone", floor(random() * 10 + 1) as "mythic"
from generate_series(1, 10000000);
```

#### Adding Rows

For this you'd use the `union` operator. `union` takes the result of multiple queries and sticks them end to end but, of course, it needs the queries to have the same columns; same names, same types in the same order. That's easy though, we can just fill out the columns we're no using with `null` values, like this:

```sql
-- Select counts
select 
    'All participants' as label, 
    null::int as keystone, 
    null::int as mythic, 
    count(*) as count
from "Participant"
union

select
    'Participants with championId 1' as label,
    null::int as keystone,
    null::int as mythic,
    count(*) as count
from "Participant"
where "championId" = 1
union

select 'Grouped by keystone' as label,
    keystone,
    null::int as mythic,
    count(*) as count
from "Participant"
where "championId" = 1
group by keystone
union

select 'Grouped by mythic' as label,
    null::int as keystone,
    mythic,
    count(*) as count
from "Participant"
where "championId" = 1
group by mythic;
```

You'll notice we're basically still just doing multiple queries here, the results are just being returned together. You mention wanting to pull out a specific set of data and reuse it for multiple subsequent queries; in that case you could use the `with` operator and do something like this instead:

```sql
-- Count all
select 
    'All participants' as label, 
    null::int as keystone, 
    null::int as mythic, 
    count(*) as count
from "Participant";

-- Count records for "championId" = 1
with s as (
    select *
    from "Participant"
    where "championId" = 1
)
select
    'Participants with championId 1' as label,
    null::int as keystone,
    null::int as mythic,
    count(*) as count
from s
union

select 'Grouped by keystone' as label,
    keystone,
    null::int as mythic,
    count(*) as count
from s
group by keystone
union

select 'Grouped by mythic' as label,
    null::int as keystone,
    mythic,
    count(*) as count
from s
group by mythic;
```

But, as mentioned in my notes at the top, this might not give you the performance boost you expect.

#### Adding Columns

The other way to achieve something similar to what you want is by doing more counts into the one query, like this:

```sql
select 
    count(*) as "all",
    count(case when "championId" = 1 then 1 else null end) as "cham1",
    count(case when "championId" = 1 and keystone = 1 then 1 else null end) as "cham1ks1",
    count(case when "championId" = 1 and keystone = 2 then 1 else null end) as "cham1ks2",
    count(case when "championId" = 1 and keystone = 3 then 1 else null end) as "cham1ks3"
    -- ..
from "Participant";
```

This really only works if you know ahead of time exactly how many values you're asking for. In your current use this isn't true – you don't know how many counts the groupings of `keystone` and `mythic` will bring back.

There are some other more exotic approach you could take if you were super keen – things like [pivot tables](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/create-pivot-table-postgresql/) or [collapsing multiple values into a json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086816/postgresql-aggregate-multiple-rows-as-json-array-based-on-specific-column) – but, as discussed at top even these two simple approaches are possibly not necessary.

Comment: This is fantastic and still very useful a month later, thank you so much! I might get back to you with more questions. I'm probably overthinking it since I'm planning ahead for when I have hundreds millions of entries, but I was just really dumstruck that I couldn't find a better way to do this.

Comment: If you will in fact have 100's of millions of records you probably shouldn't be counting them in realtime. Either have a set of counters that you increment when records are inserted or have a reporting view (that gives you all your counts) and periodically write it out to a table (search for "materialized view").